# Preserving the subtype of a parameter in Java without knowing it (or how to find it?)

Tags: java, parameters, subclassing

My Java is rusty-as-hell, and this threw me completely. I'm sure the answer is simple, but here's a simple example method that switches one `Thingy` off (if there's one already on) and another on:

```
private Thingy store;
public void switchiton(final Thingy pThingy) {
    if (store != null)
        store.endit();
    pThingy.startit();
    store = pThingy;
}
```

Problem: `pThingy` may be a subclass (e.g. `CleverThingy`) and not the superclass (`Thingy`), and `CleverThingy` overrides the `endit` method.

That code will always run the `endit` method in `Thingy` though - not the overridden one in `CleverThingy` (as it's declared as a `Thingy` and not a `CleverThingy`).

Obviously the method has no idea (and should not need one) about subclasses.

What am I missing that is staring at me in the face?

Update:

The subclass in this case is created "on the fly" (not sure of the correct term) rather than formally extended - e.g. in my `Game` class I have:

```
startthingy = new Thingy();
gamethingy = new Thingy() {
    @Override
    public void endit() {
        // override things in here
        super.endit();
    }
}

switchiton(gamethingy);  // DOES call gamethingy's overridden startit
switchiton(startthingy); // << gamethingy's overridden endit is NOT called!?
```

Comment: When `store` has the value of a reference to a `CleverThingy` instance, calling `store#endit` will perform `CleverThingy#endit` if overridden properly. I don't clearly understand your problem.

Comment: I don't either because the example I've just spend an hour debugging isn't doing that (it IS the right subtype - it isn't calling the subtype method tho!)  One small factor I missed - the parameters are declared Final (as there's a Runnable involved later in the code) - would that matter (editted the question)

Comment: No, that doesn't matter. Please provide the necessary code to replicate the problem.

Comment: I just removed all the threading (it's a LibGDX game) and the problem remains - only other factor is that the subclass is declared "on the fly" (not sure of the correct term) - I'll add that to the question

Comment: With *the subclass is declared "on the fly"* you mean it's an anonymous class or that you use a library like cglib to create the class on the fly?

Comment: I think the term is anonymous class - see extended example (Java terminology VERY rusty - sorry!)

Comment: Yes, it's an anonymous class. And again, this is really strange. Are you sure you're not confusing this with the call to `super.endit();`? Could you add a log message inside these two implementations of `endit` to make sure the exact method is being called? As I told you, this should work as expected.

Comment: I've stepped-through the code, logged messages (including a getClass for store which comes back as Game$2 which is correct I think?) but the anonymous overridden endit is never reached/run

It's notable that the anonymous code in startit IS run which is why I'm assuming the problem relates to storing the value (possibly a reference to a parameter being the issue?)

Comment: You're passing `startthingy` to the 2nd method (`switchiton()`), which `startthigy` doesn't contain an instance which overrides `endit()`. Pass `gamethingy` to the second method if you want to use the instance which is overriding `endit()`

Comment: @VinceEmigh in the first call, `store = gamethingy` will be executed, in the second call, `store.endit()` will be `gamethingy.endit()` and should work as expected. OP, are you sure your problem is not caused by calling `super.endit` in your anonymous class?

Comment: The overridden endit does call super.endit but it also does a load of other stuff first - which is definately not being run (breakpoints don't fire etc. etc.).

Comment: After attempting to replicate the issue, it's working for me. You should start a chat to continue this investigation; apparently there isn't enough information here to correctly replicate the issue (could `startIt` possibly be interfering? are you sure whatever is in the overriden method isn't being called due to the overriden method not being called? Try taking `super.endIt()` out and tell us if it prints)

Comment: Thanks for confirming that how I think it should work is how it SHOULD work - clearly there's something going on outside of this which I'm not seeing (for one thing, the person who wrote this likes overriding getter methods which scares me and may be the source of my issues - certainly Eclipse hates it!)

I'm going to vote to close the question for now I think - I can't see others getting anything from it as it's asking a question which shouldn't be a question?

Tomorrow I will start anew perhaps - thanks again!

Comment: You needeth `IThingy` I thinky.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to close this off is to answer it myself I think...

The commenters confirmed that how I thought it SHOULD work is how it actually should - this means the error is clearly elsewhere in the code...

I'm going to re-write all the anonymous classes to make them easier to debug and change a few of it's more dubious behaviours in the hope that tracks the error down

The core problem I asked - isn't really a problem tho, so...

Thanks for that!

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if this is exactly the answer you are looking for (because it changes the Thingy class instead of the switchItOn() method), but I think I found a fairly easy and safe solution to your problem. If you are worried about someone extending Thingy and not properly doing whatever the endit() method needs to do, you could make it final. This will make it so that whatever is required to do in the endit() method will always be done and that method can't be overridden.

If you still want subclasses to be able to have flexability with that class, you could try something like this:

```
public class Thingy {

    public void storeIt() {
        //do stuff
    }

    public final void callEndIt() {
        //do whatever stuff needs to be done every time in order for your program to work
        endIt();
    }

    public void endIt() {
        //this can be extended by subclasses safely
    }

}
```

Then, you can just always call callEndIt() instead of endIt() so that whatever safety precautions you need to have done get fulfilled.

Comment: My problem is kinda the other way around - it IS calling the superclass endit - but it's not calling the overridden/subclass endit which is what I expected it to do (and which does call super.endit())

Nice idea tho!

Comment: If your are using Eclipse, you should see a green triangle pointing upwards next to the endit() method in GameThingy if it is really overriding the endIt() class from Thingy. Is that there?

Comment: I don't get green triangles on Thingy but I suspect that's because it's in a different package - if I use F3 to to trace from the overridden method it works tho so...